# Kubernetes CrashLoopBackOff Error, and ports not accesible. Deploying on AKS. I am very new to this, and am honestly dying

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, deployment, azure-aks

So, I'm deploying a python backend on Azure, my first time using Azure btw.

I keep getting the CrashLoopBackOff Error, but cannot figure out why it's happening. I have spent atleast 12 hours trying to debug different issues and honestly I'm at the end of the line here.

This is what I'm getting:

```
kubectl get pods                                                 
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
backend-deployment-756db7b9f4-jmvqp   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   10 (3m16s ago)   29m
backend-deployment-756db7b9f4-qpsdg   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   10 (3m1s ago)    29m
frontend-cd44946c7-5qsl8              1/1     Running            0                63m
```

and this is the describe pods:

```
kubectl describe pod backend-deployment-756db7b9f4-jmvqp
Name:             backend-deployment-756db7b9f4-jmvqp
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             aks-nodepool1-18247916-vmss000001/10.224.0.5
Start Time:       Sat, 02 Sep 2023 15:29:09 -0230
Labels:           app=backend
                  pod-template-hash=756db7b9f4
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.1.9
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.1.9
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/backend-deployment-756db7b9f4
Containers:
  backend:
    Container ID:   containerd://1e451ddfb5978b37c4522f1c13294c8474409469268b3ed927ae6c47f29fb52a
    Image:          edifiedacr.azurecr.io/backend:latest
    Image ID:       edifiedacr.azurecr.io/backend@sha256:0b0ab62b5a5aa795a3b8cd79fc8329fed96bdb03197f1a32c4869dc6c10c203d
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 02 Sep 2023 15:40:00 -0230
      Finished:     Sat, 02 Sep 2023 15:40:00 -0230
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  7
    Liveness:       http-get http://:80/health/live delay=15s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:80/health/ready delay=15s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-m7mr5 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-m7mr5:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  12m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/backend-deployment-756db7b9f4-jmvqp to aks-nodepool1-18247916-vmss000001
  Normal   Created    11m (x4 over 12m)    kubelet            Created container backend
  Normal   Started    11m (x4 over 12m)    kubelet            Started container backend
  Normal   Pulled     10m (x5 over 12m)    kubelet            Container image "edifiedacr.azurecr.io/backend:latest" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    2m1s (x57 over 12m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container backend in pod backend-deployment-756db7b9f4-jmvqp_default(72a60525-9f03-4d87-bfd6-f4171a5ccbc5)
```

If you want my main code, here it is:
app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort  # Import abort
from flask_cors import CORS
import logging  # Import logging
import requests
import textrazor
import openai
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all routes

HUGGINGFACE_API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/Shobhank-iiitdwd/BERT_summary"
API_HEADERS = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer api_key"
}
razor_API_KEY_2 = "api_key"

openai.api_key = "api_key"

import time

def summarize_text(text, retries=3, delay=5):
    payload = {"inputs": text}
    for i in range(retries):
        response = requests.post(HUGGINGFACE_API_URL, headers=API_HEADERS, json=payload)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                summary = response.json()[0]['summary_text']
                return summary
            except (KeyError, TypeError):
                print("Unexpected API response:", response.json())
                return "Error in summarizing text."
        elif response.status_code == 503:  # Service Unavailable
            print(f"API is unavailable. Retry {i+1}/{retries}. Waiting for {delay} seconds.")
            time.sleep(delay)
        else:
            print(f"API call failed. Status code: {response.status_code}, Error message: {response.text}")
            return "Error in summarizing text."
    return "Max retries reached. Could not summarize text."


def reference_links(text):
    razor_API_KEY = "api_key"
    textrazor.api_key = razor_API_KEY
    client = textrazor.TextRazor(extractors=["entities", "topics"])
    response = client.analyze(text)
    
    wikipedia_links = []
    for entity in response.entities():
        if entity.wikipedia_link:
            wikipedia_links.append(entity.wikipedia_link)
            
    return wikipedia_links

def extract_topics(text):
    textrazor.api_key = razor_API_KEY_2  # Different API key
    client = textrazor.TextRazor(extractors=["topics"])
    response = client.analyze(text)
    
    topics = []
    for topic in response.topics():
        if topic.score > 0.3:
            topics.append(topic.label)
        
    return topics

@app.route('/expand_note', methods=['POST'])
def expand_note():  # Removed 'text' parameter
    content = request.json
    if not content or 'note' not in content:
        abort(400, "Missing 'note' in request.")

    original_note = content['note']  # Corrected from 'text' to 'note'
    prompt = f"Expand the following note:\n{original_note}\n"

    try:
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            model="text-davinci-003",
            prompt=prompt,
            max_tokens=100
        )
        expanded_text = response['choices'][0]['text'].strip()
        return jsonify({'expanded_note': expanded_text})
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to expand note: {e}")
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to expand note"}), 500
    
#for liveness and readiness:
@app.route('/health/live', methods=['GET'])
def liveness():
    return jsonify({"status": "OK", "message": "Application is live"}), 200


@app.route('/health/ready', methods=['GET'])
def readiness():
    # Implement additional logic to check database, etc. here if needed
    return jsonify({"status": "OK", "message": "Application is ready"}), 200



@app.route('/api/edify', methods=['POST'])
def edify():
    content = request.json
    text_to_edify = content.get("text", "")
    
    # Create a ThreadPoolExecutor to run the functions in parallel
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future_summary = executor.submit(summarize_text, text_to_edify)
        future_references = executor.submit(reference_links, text_to_edify)
        future_topics = executor.submit(extract_topics, text_to_edify)
        
        summary = future_summary.result()
        references = future_references.result()
        topics = future_topics.result()

    if summary == "Max retries reached. Could not summarize text.":
        return jsonify({"summary": summary, "references": references, "topics": topics, "error": "APIUnavailable"})
    else:
        return jsonify({"summary": summary, "references": references, "topics": topics, "error": None})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Furthermore, this is my dockerfile (I had to include the platform cause of the stupid mac m2 chips):

```
# Using an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-alpine

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Installing any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Defining environment variable
ENV NAME World
```

View all code on github: `https://github.com/joshuakatt/edified.io`

I've tried:

```
kubectl logs -f backend-deployment-756db7b9f4-jmvqp -c backend --previous
```

but to no avail.

I've also added this: command:

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "sleep 1000"]
```

this keeps the container running, but then I get these:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  47s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/backend-deployment-7cb97565fb-vw2r5 to aks-nodepool1-18247916-vmss000001
  Normal   Pulled     47s               kubelet            Container image "edifiedacr.azurecr.io/backend:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    47s               kubelet            Created container backend
  Normal   Started    47s               kubelet            Started container backend
  Warning  Unhealthy  7s (x4 over 27s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.244.1.10:80/health/ready": dial tcp 10.244.1.10:80: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  7s (x3 over 27s)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.244.1.10:80/health/live": dial tcp 10.244.1.10:80: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Killing    7s                kubelet            Container backend failed liveness probe, will be restarted
(backendEnv) joshuakattapuram@Joshuas-MacBook-Air kubernetes-configs % kubectl get deployments                                 
NAME                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
backend-deployment   0/2     1            0           43m
frontend             1/1     1            1           97m
```

Update: I've removed the liveness and readiness ports. But I'm still getting the errors:kubectl `get pods NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE backend-deployment-76465ff6b9-g9phr   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4 (19s ago)   115s backend-deployment-76465ff6b9-grxn4   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4 (27s ago)   117s frontend-cd44946c7-5qsl8              1/1     Running            0             22h` and this is my .yaml file  `containers: image: edifiedacr.azurecr.io/backend:latest imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent ports: - containerPort: 80`

Comment: Please match the container port with liveness port and readiness port defined in backend deployment yaml definition.  The probes are failing hence the pod is getting restarted

Comment: Like Nataraj pointed out, the issue is likely the probes failing. Try removing them from the deployment manifest and test to confirm.

Comment: @CSharpRocks Thanks so much for your advice. I have updated the code. I still ham struggling with a few things, would it be alright If i asked them to you?

Comment: @CSharpRocks I've updated the op. Please let me know if you require any additional info or would be able to spare a few minutes of your busy with a short call/messages Thanks.

Comment: Your Dockerfile is missing the `CMD` line.  It should look something like `CMD ./app.py`; there are other ways to run a dev server using the `flask` command-line wrapper or more production-oriented servers like GUnicorn as well.  Without a `CMD` the container doesn't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as David Maze mentioned in one of the comments to your original question, the reason why your backend container is crashing is that you haven't specified a CMD / ENTRYPOINT in your backend Dockerfile so the container will not start any local web server hosting your flask app. Add a CMD / ENTRYPOINT just like yo've done in your frontend Dockerfile and you should be good to go.

Secondly, as a good practice, you really shouldn't expose your flask app on port 80. This will require your container to run with elevated privileges (only root can bind to ports below 1024) which is an unnecessary security threat. Choose a higher port number to expose your app and make changes in your Dockerfile and Deployment YAML. In your Service YAML you can still expose over port 80, making sure that you point it to the correct container port, just like for your frontend component.